# Rinning docker running instance with LAMP got python not found error

Tags: python, docker

in my Kubuntu 18.04 I installed docker-ce and running LAMP instance suffer error that python not found:

```
$ docker-compose up -d --build 
Building web
Step 1/3 : FROM php:7.2-apache
 ---> 35e5c60e1f7d
Step 2/3 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y     libfreetype6-dev     libwebp-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev     nano     git-core     curl     build-essential     openssl     libssl-dev     libgmp-dev     libldap2-dev     netcat     sqlite3     libsqlite3-dev      && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git      && cd node      && ./configure      && make      && sudo make install     docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ &&     docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql pdo_sqlite zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif && a2enmod rewrite
 ---> Running in 65d838fde10d
Get:1 http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [39.1 kB]
Get:2 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [118 kB]
Get:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB]
Get:4 http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [82.1 kB]
Get:5 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7897 kB]
Get:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [884 B]
Fetched 8187 kB in 2s (3674 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
...
Reading package lists...
Get:42 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 xauth amd64 1:1.0.10-1 [40.3 kB]

debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 21.1 MB in 3s (6954 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package less.
...
Setting up libfreetype6-dev:amd64 (2.9.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
Cloning into 'node'...
Checking out files: 100% (32035/32035), done.
./configure: 4: exec: python: not found
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y     libfreetype6-dev     libwebp-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev     nano     git-core     curl     build-essential     openssl     libssl-dev     libgmp-dev     libldap2-dev     netcat     sqlite3     libsqlite3-dev      && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git      && cd node      && ./configure      && make      && sudo make install     docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ &&     docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql pdo_sqlite zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif && a2enmod rewrite' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I payed attention at message :

```
since apt-utils is not installed
```

But I have installed this package :

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep apt-utils
apt-utils                                       install
```

and rebooted my OS after installation

```
# docker info                                           
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 3
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 19.03.2
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc version: 425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.15.0-20-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 7.711GiB
 Name: serge-at-hoe
 ID: 4IWA:LRTR:4UJS:FEDE:PCOJ:ZFFB:RLXR:LRPT:7QBI:XGLY:VVIV:TNJQ
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

My web/Dockerfile.yml :

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    nano \
    git-core \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    netcat \
    sqlite3 \
    libsqlite3-dev \
     && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git \
     && cd node \
     && ./configure \
     && make \
     && sudo make install \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql pdo_sqlite zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif \
&& a2enmod rewrite
```

COPY virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

I found in my OS :

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15+
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.15+

$ dpkg --get-selections | grep python
libpython-stdlib:amd64                          install
libpython2.7:amd64                              install
libpython2.7-minimal:amd64                      install
libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64                       install
libpython3-stdlib:amd64                         install
libpython3.6:amd64                              install
libpython3.6-minimal:amd64                      install
libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64                       install
python                                          install
python-appindicator                             install
python-apt-common                               install
python-asn1crypto                               install
python-backports.ssl-match-hostname             install
python-cached-property                          install
python-cairo:amd64                              install
python-certifi                                  install
python-cffi-backend                             install
python-chardet                                  install
python-cryptography                             install
python-dbus                                     install
python-docker                                   install
python-dockerpty                                install
python-dockerpycreds                            install
python-docopt                                   install
python-enchant                                  install
python-enum34                                   install
python-funcsigs                                 install
python-functools32                              install
python-gi                                       install
python-glade2                                   install
python-gobject                                  install
python-gobject-2                                install
python-gtk2                                     install
python-gtksourceview2                           install
python-idna                                     install
python-ipaddress                                install
python-jsonschema                               install
python-minimal                                  install
python-mock                                     install
python-mysql.connector                          install
python-openssl                                  install
python-paramiko                                 install
python-pbr                                      install
python-pexpect                                  install
python-pkg-resources                            install
python-ptyprocess                               install
python-pyasn1                                   install
python-pyodbc                                   install
python-pysqlite2                                install
python-qt4-dbus                                 install
python-requests                                 install
python-six                                      install
python-talloc                                   install
python-texttable                                install
python-urllib3                                  install
python-websocket                                install
python-yaml                                     install
python2.7                                       install
python2.7-minimal                               install
python3                                         install
python3-apport                                  install
python3-apt                                     install
python3-aptdaemon                               install
python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets                   install
python3-asn1crypto                              install
python3-blinker                                 install
python3-bs4                                     install
python3-cairo:amd64                             install
python3-certifi                                 install
python3-cffi-backend                            install
python3-chardet                                 install
python3-commandnotfound                         install
python3-cryptography                            install
python3-cups                                    install
python3-cupshelpers                             install
python3-dbus                                    install
python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5                     install
python3-debconf                                 install
python3-debian                                  install
python3-defer                                   install
python3-distro-info                             install
python3-distupgrade                             install
python3-feedparser                              install
python3-gdbm:amd64                              install
python3-gi                                      install
python3-gi-cairo                                install
python3-html5lib                                install
python3-httplib2                                install
python3-idna                                    install
python3-jwt                                     install
python3-lxml:amd64                              install
python3-macaroonbakery                          install
python3-mako                                    install
python3-markupsafe                              install
python3-minimal                                 install
python3-nacl                                    install
python3-oauthlib                                install
python3-olefile                                 install
python3-pexpect                                 install
python3-pil:amd64                               install
python3-pkg-resources                           install
python3-problem-report                          install
python3-protobuf                                install
python3-ptyprocess                              install
python3-pymacaroons                             install
python3-pyqt5                                   install
python3-pyxattr                                 install
python3-renderpm:amd64                          install
python3-reportlab                               install
python3-reportlab-accel:amd64                   install
python3-requests                                install
python3-requests-unixsocket                     install
python3-rfc3339                                 install
python3-sip                                     install
python3-six                                     install
python3-software-properties                     install
python3-systemd                                 install
python3-tz                                      install
python3-uno                                     install
python3-update-manager                          install
python3-urllib3                                 install
python3-webencodings                            install
python3-xapian                                  install
python3-xdg                                     install
python3-xkit                                    install
python3-yaml                                    install
python3.6                                       install
python3.6-minimal                               install
```

Can it be that docker runs invalid python and how fix it ?

```
$ lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
4.15.0-20-generic
x86_64
$ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Python is not there in the container. 
Try modifying as below

```
RUN apt-get update && \ 
apt-get install -y \ 
python \
```

It requires python to be installed in container before doing configure.